# Looping through the elements of pairs of lists

Tags: python

I have a list of tuples, which in turn consist of two lists again. For example:

```
big_list = [
    (["A", "B", "C"], [1, 2]),
    (["X", "Y"], [9, 8, 7]),
    ]
```

I'd like to call some function on each combination of (letter, number).
I currently have a big ugly set of three nested for loops, along these lines:

```
for (letters, numbers) in big_list:
    for letter in letters:
        for number in numbers:
            do_stuff(letter, number)
```

That is, I'd like `do_stuff` to be called once, for each combination of (letter, number) present in my list.

Is it feasible to collapse these three loops into one or two? Preferably in a way that isn't ugly and unPythonic?

Comment: Nothing wrong with what you've got. It's the most straightforward way to do it.

Comment: @acdr : Please take a look at second answer, I have done it with one loop and a map

Answer (score 3):

I think `itertools` may help:

```
import itertools

for (letters, numbers) in big_list:
    for (letter, number) in itertools.product(letters, numbers):
        do_stuff(letter, number)
```

This saves you a loop, so now you only have one nested loop to deal with. And I think it's bit more Pythonic.

Answer (score 1):

You could also combine [`itertools.product`](https://docs.python.org/3/library/itertools.html#itertools.product) with [`starmap`](https://docs.python.org/3/library/itertools.html#itertools.starmap) and [`chain.from_iterable`](https://docs.python.org/3/library/itertools.html#itertools.chain.from_iterable):

```
from itertools import chain, starmap, product
for l, n in chain.from_iterable(starmap(product, big_list)):
    print(l, n)
```

Of course, whether that's more clear is a matter of opinion. Or just use a generator expression:

```
for l, n in (p for ls, ns in big_list for p in product(ls, ns)):
     print(l ,n)
```

Both ways, the result (as `list`) is `[('A', 1), ('A', 2), ('B', 1), ('B', 2), ('C', 1), ('C', 2), ('X', 9), ('X', 8), ('X', 7), ('Y', 9), ('Y', 8), ('Y', 7)]`.